# Why the "Use of undeclared type UITableView" happened in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am new to `Swift`. I created a second `swift file` call `DeviceInfo.swift` and add a `UIViewcontroller` in `Main.storyboard`.

I also add a `UITableView` in `UIViewcontroller(DeviceInfo)`.

But the error **`Use of undeclared type 'UITableView'`** show after I connect the `UITableView` to `DeviceInfo.swift` via `command + left`. The error show like the following.
[image]

**Question**

**1. Why the `Use of undeclared type 'UITableView'` happened ? How to solve it ?**

**2. Show I connect the `dataSource` and `delegate` to `UIViewcontroller(DeviceInfo)`?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1.`import UIKit`

2.To connect `delegate` and `dataSource`,
click the point and drag to your tableView.
[image]

Comment: You mean , connect the `delegate` and `dataSource` of `UITableView` to the `View` not `UIViewController` ? Why ?

Comment: I made a mistake. Yes, it should be UIViewController. Because your UIViewController need to know about how to show the data,  and tableView need to ask UIViewController to do something which tableView can't do it by itself. Such as `didSelectedRowAtIndex` or else.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add `import UIKit` at the top of your file, in the area where you've already got `import Foundation`. Without UIKit imported, your object doesn't know what a UITableView is.

Comment: About question 2 , what should I connect for `datasource` and `delegate` ? `UIViewController` or` View` ?

Comment: @Martin UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` in in UIKit framework, you didn't imported that. SO `import UIKit.`

In your `viewDidLod`:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

In your .h file you can do:

```
@interface YourClassName : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

And make sure you connected the tableView with an `IBOutlet`.
    [image: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>]

Comment: About question 2 , what should I connect for `datasource` and `delegate` ? `UIViewController` or` View` ?