# UITableView is not displaying labels, nor cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have an array that holds comments that users reply to a post, they are saved in Parse.com, but it seems that when I try to display them in the tableView, they are not showing up. This is what I'm using to display the comments in the tableView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row] as String

    return cell
}
```

I already tried some other variations of the code and some other posts on here trying to find an answer, but still no luck. 
I can confirm that the data is saved in Parse, but it doesn't seem to be displayed in the app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot configure tableview datasource.

```
class DetailViewContoller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

...
...
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    commentTableView.delegate = self
    commentTableView.dataSource = self
```

to use tableview you have to configure tableview delegate and datasource.

Comment: I tried to add it and it gives me the following error: **use of undeclared type 'UITableViewDatasource'** Do I have to import something else before using the dataSource?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017622/why-the-use-of-undeclared-type-uitableview-happened-in-swift  .Maybe import UIKit solve this prblem like this question.

Comment: The 's' of the DataSource was in lower case, after I changed it to uppercase it fixed the problem. It works fine now. It also displays the comments. I've been trying to figure this out all day. You saved the day! Thank you!